# Stored Procedure Multiple loops only gets first loop data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm having some trouble with a procedure that I'm calling.

The Procedure has 2 loops, one for the connections to other databases in the same network, and another to get the data from each connect, but the problem is that it only gets the first pack of data from the first connection. I'm not sure but maybe i'm doing something wrong in the second loop, forgetting something. This is the second time i'm doing such thing and the first time its to ugh complex.

Here is the code of the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `firians`.`sincronizarAgencias` ()
BEGIN
declare nomeAgencia varchar(255);
declare ultimaAgencia int default false;
declare terminouPicagens int default false;

declare agenciasCur cursor for select ip from agencia;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ultimaAgencia = TRUE;

open agenciasCur;
nomeAgenciasLoop: LOOP

    FETCH agenciasCur INTO nomeAgencia;

    IF ultimaAgencia THEN
        close agenciasCur; 
        LEAVE nomeAgenciasLoop;
    END IF;

    SELECT nomeAgencia;

    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS temp_agencia_view;
    SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW temp_agencia_view as select data, idempregado, idsociedade, nif, tipo from `', nomeAgencia, '`'); 
    select @query; 
    PREPARE stmt from @query; 
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    blocoPicagens: BEGIN
        declare newData DATETIME;
        declare newIdEmpregado VARCHAR(45);
        declare newIdSociedade bigint(20);
        declare newNif varchar(15);
        declare newTipo varchar(45);

        declare ultimaPicagem int default false;

        -- SELECT data, idempregado, idsociedade, nif, tipo from temp_agencia_view;

        DECLARE picagensCursor cursor for select data, idempregado, idsociedade, nif, tipo from temp_agencia_view;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ultimaPicagem := TRUE;

        open picagensCursor;
        picagensLoop: LOOP
            fetch picagensCursor into newData, newIdEmpregado, newIdSociedade, newNif, newTipo;

            IF ultimaPicagem THEN
                -- SET ultimaPicagem := false;
                close picagensCursor;
                DROP VIEW IF EXISTS temp_agencia_view; 
                LEAVE picagensLoop;
            END IF;

            INSERT INTO `firians`.`assiduidade`(`data`,`idempregado`,`idsociedade`,`tipo`,`nif`)
            VALUES
            (newData, newIdEmpregado, newIdSociedade, newTipo, newNif);

            INSERT INTO `firians`.`assiduidadebackup`(`data`,`idempregado`,`idsociedade`,`tipo`,`nif`)
            VALUES
            (newData, newIdEmpregado, newIdSociedade, newTipo, newNif);

            set @updateRowQuery = CONCAT('DELETE FROM `', nomeAgencia,'` WHERE idempregado = ', newIdEmpregado, ' AND idsociedade = ', newIdSociedade, ' AND tipo = ', newTipo, ' AND data LIKE \'', newData, "'"); 
            select @updateRowQuery;
            PREPARE stmtUpdate from @updateRowQuery; 
            EXECUTE stmtUpdate; 
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtUpdate;

        END LOOP picagensLoop;

    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS temp_agencia_view;
        -- select * from temp_agencia_view;           
    END blocoPicagens;

END LOOP nomeAgenciasLoop;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS temp_agencia_view;
END
```

Can you help me?

Regards,

Elkas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that MySQL [does not support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) `CREATE VIEW` from within a prepared statement.  You could use a temporary table instead:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_agencia_tbl
    select data, idempregado, idsociedade, nif, tipo from `', nomeAgencia, '`
');
```

However, this approach seems like overkill, as one could use the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) syntax from within the prepared statement to avoid the second cursor altogether:

```
SET @q1 = CONCAT('
  INSERT INTO firians.assiduidade
          (data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif)
    SELECT data, idempragado, idsociedade, tipo, nif FROM `', nomeAgencia, '`
');
SET @q2 = CONCAT('
  INSERT INTO firians.assiduidadebackup
          (data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif)
    SELECT data, idempragado, idsociedade, tipo, nif FROM `', nomeAgencia, '`
');
SET @q3 = CONCAT('TRUNCATE `', nomeAgencia, '`');
```

But *even this* still seems like overkill, as one could also dispense with the first cursor by using  [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to construct a single such [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) statement which uses [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine the tables:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('
    INSERT INTO firians.assiduidade
            (data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif)'
  , GROUP_CONCAT('
      SELECT data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif FROM `', ip, '`'
      SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
  ) INTO @q1
, CONCAT('
    INSERT INTO firians.assiduidadebackup
            (data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif)'
  , GROUP_CONCAT('
      SELECT data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif FROM `', ip, '`'
      SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
  ) INTO @q2
, CONCAT('
    DELETE FROM ', GROUP_CONCAT('`', ip, '`'), '
          USING ', GROUP_CONCAT('`', ip, '`')
  ) INTO @q3
FROM agencia;
```

But, with all that said, using variable tables in this manner is generally an indication of poor database design.  Instead of multiple tables with similar schema, you will probably find that a single table which combines all the disparate records (with an additional column to indicate any differentiation, such as from which table the data originated) will be considerably easier.  For example, the above would then simply reduce to:

```
INSERT INTO firians.assiduidade
        (data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif)
  SELECT data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif FROM CombinedTable;

INSERT INTO firians.assiduidadebackup
        (data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif)
  SELECT data, idempregado, idsociedade, tipo, nif FROM CombinedTable;

TRUNCATE CombinedTable;
```

Note that I have not addressed concurrency concerns in this answer, as they weren't addressed in the original SP; obviously, if concurrency could be a problem, you should consider locking strategies such as encompassing these actions within a transaction.

It might also be worth pointing out that, whilst one must concatenate SQL identifiers into prepared statements as you have been doing, values can be passed to a prepared statement upon execution (e.g. into your `DELETE` statement; indeed that statement could have been prepared only once per iteration of the first cursor and executed with different values on each iteration of the second cursor).

Comment: Sorry for answer just now, I didn't had a proper internet connection in the weekend. I don't know if its a problem with a view because in the first iteration of the first loops its all OK. Only in the second one it stops on the beginning of the process (stops at select data, idempregado, idsociedade, nif, tipo from temp_agencia_view; It return 0 results).
But I'll try to use you're approach. Give me just a couple of hours.

Comment: Abou the concurrency, if I understand it correctly, It will be no problem because this table will be used only in the procedure. No onle else (in the code or users) knows about the existence of this.

Comment: Thanks mate. The view was the problem. Maybe you can answer me this question now. Why in the 1st iteration it was all ok and in the second one i didn't get any data?